# slideshow made with javascript exceeds call stack

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to build a simple self-running slideshow with javascript. When I execute the following code I get an error message that the maximum call stack size has been exceeded. I'm not sure exactly what this means, but the computer can't find the image's location and lists it as `undefined`. Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thank you for your help

```
var slide = 0 /* the tracker for every picture */
var left_arrow = document.getElementById("arrow_left")
var right_arrow = document.getElementById("arrow_right")
var gallery = document.getElementById("picture")
slideshow(0);
length = images.length - 1

function slideshow(slide) {
  images = ["blackchicken.jpg", "bantamchicken.jpg", "goldenegg.jpeg"]
  console.log(slide)
  pic = '<img src="' + images[slide] + '">'
  console.log(pic)
  gallery.innerHTML = pic
  slide += 1;
  if (slide == length) {
    slide = 0
  }
  setTimeout(slideshow(), 3000); // Change image every 3 seconds
}
```

Comment: Don't use `()` with `setTimeout` e.g. `setTimeout(slideshow, 3000);` Of course, there are other issues with your code, but this should solve your immediate issue.

Comment: @Gavin as an extension to your comment: using `()` executes the function, and it enters in a loop where `slideshow` function is constantly calling more `slideshow` functions. If you use only `slideshow` you are referencing that function and not executing it, so, like that `setTimeout` calls the `slideshow` function only when it's needed

Comment: @HugoFarji I thought about adding an explanation, but you did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: In the line `setTimeout(slideshow(), 3000);`,  `setTimeout` function calls `slideshow` function that calls `setTimeout` function that calls `slideshow` and so on... That's why you get Stack Overflow (tm)

Comment: Both of you are in the correct answer, somebody post it as answer

Comment: thank you for explaining why i get the error message. when i do `console.log(pic)` i get `undefined` as an output. do you know why?

Comment: ok, i think the parameter cannot be used as an index for an array. I removed slide as a parameter and everything worked fine. thanks!

Comment: @st4rgut you can use a parameter as an index but in your case it is overriding global slide variable in the function scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is calling itself at

```
setTimeout(slideshow(), 3000);
                    ^^
```

And this is filling the stack in an infinite loop, which explains your problem.